# I am looking for a language that can give a large amount of information about functions as objects

Tags: programming-languages

I am looking for a statically typed language that not only treats functions as first class objects, but can read the number of inputs, and their type, as well as number of outputs as well as their types.

I think this might be possible with scala if I monkey patched the Function1 trait, but that seems pretty in-elegant.

Comment: This kind of ability is called "reflection", and it is commonly available in dynamically typed languages like Ruby.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far the languages that I believe are able to do this are:

Javascript, Ruby and C#.

Answer (score 1):

In a statically-typed language, that information is present in the type of the function. If code typechecks, it's because all that information matches up correctly.

It's true that that information is generally not available in an explicit form or at runtime, but that's because it's not usually useful (additionally, it violates [Parametricity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametricity)). It's hard to provide more advice without knowing what you want the information for.

Comment: Its a bit conceptual, basically creating a graph where each node knows the type of information that it holds and each edge is an arbitrary function. Once you specify what functions it can use, input and output nodes and a couple of examples it should be able to do something similar to ML but with A*.

Comment: Does "ML" mean machine learning, ML the programming language, or something else?